# Three.js How to use quaternion to rotate camera (part 2)

Tags: three.js, quaternions

Can anyone modify this basic file

http://jsfiddle.net/koweiny/MQkKW/

so that the **camera** (not the cube) rotates around the cube using quaternions?

I've been searching for an example around the web and I haven't found any. Found indications simply don't work. And I've checked that there are also many people looking for an example. A simple rotation would be enough to illustrate the mechanism.

By the way:

```
THREE.Quaternion.slerp(a, b, c, d);
```

What are *a*, *b*, *c* and *d* used for in that function? Is slerp the best way to rotate a camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quaternions are used to set an object's orientation, not to rotate an object around a another object. So the answer to your question is "No". Sorry.

```
THREE.Quaternion.slerp( fromQuaternion, toQuaternion, quaternionToSet, fractionOfTheWay);
```

You can change an camera's orientation by setting either `camera.rotation` or `camera.quaternion`.

three.js r.55

Comment: Ummm... what a disappointment. Thank you very much anyway. :-)